# Genetic basis of prescriptivism

Tags: personality, genetics

Perhaps I'm searching using the wrong term, but by prescriptivism I mean:

- holding strong beliefs and
- having a strong desire to impose them on others

I know that in the US nowadays these two might tingle "conservatism" for some, but given the [horseshoe theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_theory) I'd rather go for a more explicit term.

I guess these two items correlate with some personality traits as well... So has there been any research in genetic correlations of these two items even if less directly?

Comment: It occurred to me after asking the above that "religious extremism" might be a more sexy research topic these days, which correlates well to what I call prescriptivism above...And sure enough something came up, although trauma rathar gene related: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0028393217301318

Comment: So you are asking if there have been linkage studies for holding beliefs and imposing them?

Comment: @AliceD: yes, that's what I'm asking. Feel free to edit the question if I wasn't clear enough. Also, searching for genetic and fundamentalism in the same phrase tends to turn up "genetics fundamentalism" discussions such as http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1357034X04047853

Comment: After looking at some recent GWAS studies on personality (disorders) [e.g.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5278898/) it's probably too early/ambitions to ask a question like this.